# How can I know which Qt quick version in my system before importing that?

Tags: qt, qml

By `qVersion()` I will get the Qt version as `5.13.1`

But in QML I use `import QtQuick 2.12`. How to get the QtQuick version  C++/QML (`2.12`)?

Comment: I think that your question needs a bit more information on what you're trying to achieve and what the actual problem/question is that you're facing.
Keep in mind that the Qt version will be different from the QtQuick version as they are two separate software components. You can find more information in the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html#versions

Comment: That's what Joel, I am asking to print Qt Quick version. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to "print the QtQuick version" (as per your comment on your question). However, reading the docs it seems that it is just a 1:1 mapping between the Qt version and the QtQuick version.

[This Qt forum post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/50948/how-to-find-in-documenation-the-qtquick-versions-for-a-qt-version) appears to confirm that post:

> Every new Qt release gets a new QtQuick version. It's a 1 to 1 mapping so far: Qt 5.x has QtQuick 2.x (so, Qt 5.4 has QtQuick 2.4). You can check that by opening the documentation for - for example - Rectangle or Item.

Here's the corresponding documentation that shows the mapping of the Qt version and the QtQuick(Controls) version: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html
From that it would appear that you need to use/import QtQuick `2.13` when you're using Qt `5.13`.

Comment: That's not necessarily the version imported in the QML file: One can import QtQuick 2.0 just fine even with latest Qt, if one doesn't need a feature from a newer version of QtQuick.